# Getting Error read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding' while reading excel(xlsx) files into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my code is
'''
DumpDF=pd.read_excel(Report,encoding='cp1252')
''

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model1_final.py", line 132, in 
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
**TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'**
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2021 09:16:40] "[37mPOST /predict HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -

Tried replacing encoding with encoding_override, still got same TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "model1_final.py", line 132, in 
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util_decorators.py", line 299, in wrapper
return func(*args, **kwargs)
**TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding_override'**
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Feb/2021 09:16:40] "[37mPOST /predict HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -

Comment: why are you using encoding='cp1252'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see here [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) does not take/need a (keyword) argument called 'encoding'.